# Handle the Exception and Continue the process without termination in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am working on java, I read huge no.of XML files & insert them into ORACLE database but while inserting I am getting Exception, Then my program terminates without processing remaining records, Could any one please help me out from this situation, I want to read the files until unless they finished without termination of program while exception occurs.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet explaining what you are trying to do and what should happen if you get an exception?

Answer (score 3):

```
for (File f : myFileArray) { //Or whatever you have
   try {
       // your code which might throw exception
   } catch ( <Your exception name here> e) {
       System.err.println("File failed: " + f.getAbsoultePath() );
       continue; //if more code follows the try catch block, otherwise omit it
   }
}
```

Since you did not gave any code snippet for what you actually do, I tried a guess.

As the comments suggest, you use try/catch-Blocks for handling exceptions in Java.

A good tutorial is imho

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/index.html

Chapter 80 and 81.

Comment: Actually @Joey - you are wrong.  The `continue` IS within an iteration statement.  The iteration statement is not required to be the immediately enclosing statement.  Admittedly, the `continue` is redundant in this snippet, but it is perfectly legal.

Comment: Is it not the case that, if an exception is thrown and catched, the code after the try/catch will be executed? And we do not want that for a failed one. Thats why i commented the continue.

Comment: @user1204330 If you want to skip the code after the `try/catch`, why not include it into the `try` block?

Comment: Thats what I would normally do, but I want to make sure this potential error source will be removed since the questioner seems unfamiliar with exception handling.